# How to log binary data with GNU screen

Tags: logs, gnu-screen, serial-port, binary

I am using GNU screen to open a serial port and log incoming **binary** data to a file. The command I use is:

```
screen -S mySession -L -Logfile data_out /dev/ttyUSB0 115200, cs8
```

At some point the recording halted. The explanation seems to be that at some point I received the characters 0x11 and 0x13 as a part of the binary stream, which apparently are special terminal characters (Ctrl+Q and Ctrl+S or XON/XOFF?) and affect GNU screen.

Is there a way to log **binary** data via GNU screen without such issues arising?

Answer (score 0):

If your system did actually receive an XOFF (from the remote system) and took whatever incident action, it is because :

- 1/ The software flow control is enabled on both sides
- 2/ The remote system is getting to much input from your system with regards to its processing/buffering capabilities.

Since it is wrongdoing to disable flow control, you should check if the remote system can handle hardware flow control (RTS/CTS) and enable it (on both sides) while disabling software flow control (on both sides),

Alternatively, and as a quick&dirty workaround, you can try reducing significantly the communication speed and/or increase remote's input buffer.